# Can not completely clear richtextbox

Tags: c#

I have a RichTextBox onto which I write long lists of data using a simple write method (see down)

I use vertical scrolbar, and writing and clearing is fine. 
The problem is with new text after clearing the text.

I use textbox.clear(); which clears the box OK, but when new text arrives, the old (cleared!) text shows up again, followed by the new text.

I have also tried:
ResetText, Refresh, Update. dispose, Text =" , richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear(); (dont have that one). 
Have also tried new textbox  = new textbox, all for no avail.

The text shows again and again, until I reset the application.
I have seen several form threads on that one, but non helped.

My guess: I use both scroll bars. A scrollbar must have a buffer, The data is kept somewhere in the active scrollbar buffer?

Any (good) idea will be blessed.

This is how I write / erase the text in the richtextbox: 
(simplified. mainDisplay is a RichTextBox)

```
 public void mainDisplayText(string text)
    {
            this.mainDisplay.AppendText(text);
            this.mainDisplay.ScrollToCaret();
    }  

private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Have tried all these options:
        this.mainDisplay.Text = "";  //or
        this.mainDisplay.Clear();    //or
        this.mainDisplay.SelectAll();     //or
        this.mainDisplay.SelectedText = "";
    }
```

Comment: can you post other code?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/149698/how-can-i-delete-selected-text-from-a-richtextbox

Comment: you said you tried dispose, if you disposed your richtextbox and the text came back its not the richtextbox, it must be the string your passing in, dispose will require you to make a new richtextbox next time, and if its new it will have no way of knowing the previous richtextboxes content

Comment: Thanks, you are right, its is a text behind. (I know what dispose means.)

As I wrote, I guess it is a text behind, used for the scrol bar, but I have no idea how I can reach it.

Comment: to bumbumpaw: My program is many classes, methods and several thousands lines. I wish I knew what to show...
I tried building a basic program that does the same write / clear, and it seems OK.

Comment: What is the value of `text` variable that you pass to `mainDisplayText()`?

Answer (score 1):

You're reusing the same string, so:

```
this.mainDisplay.Clear();
text = string.Empty;
```

Should do the trick :)

Comment: Well, thanks to all who tried. 
As nothing worked so far, I realize the problem is not in the textbox, and because my program is large (and not easy to debug) I decided to leave this problem for later time.
Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, try exchanging Clear() and .Text=string.Empty in the question source. A Clear *before* assign .Text="" as Tyress shows, works for me. Strange indeed. A Clear() after Text=string.Empty seems to bring back previous content ! Strange thing is.. sofar Clear() worked for me in several contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Strange indeed. Could this be some issue in .net 4.7.x ? Since last week I compile everything in 4.7.2 and this problem has surfaced here also. Clear() seems to bring back the .Text content. So a Clear() *after* Text="" does not work.